# Array os arrays transformation to d3.js json format

Tags: ruby, json

I have this array of arrays:

```
[["abc", "123"], ["cde", "456"], ["cde", "674"]]
```

And I want this array of arrays arranged in this way:

```
{ "name": "test", "children": [ {"name": "abc", "children": [ {"name": "123"} ]}, {"name": "cde", "children": [ { "name": "456"},{"name": "674"} ]}]}
```

How can I make this transformation in ruby language?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not valid Ruby object.

Comment: I don't know why there are 2 -ve votes on this question looks like a good one.

Comment: @x13 Not the first array. The problem is your expected output. Have you ever tried these by yourself before posting them?

Comment: Of course sawa, if I had not tried I did not come here to put the question... thanks for all your help ;)

Comment: It would be a good question if the OP had supplied the code showing an attempt to solve the question. See "[Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)".

Comment: @theTinMan okay I agree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 require 'json'
 src_arr= [["abc", "123"], ["cde", "456"], ["cde", "674"]]
 tmp = {} # to collect all common node first
 src_arr.each do |arr|
     if node = tmp[arr.first] # check if node exists
       node['children'] << {'name' => arr.last} # append of exists
     else
       # add node if does not exists
       tmp[arr.first] = {'name' => arr.first,'children' => [{'name' => arr.last}]}
     end
   end
 tree = {'name' => 'test','children' => tmp.values}
 puts tree

#=> {"name"=>"test", "children"=>[{"name"=>"abc", "children"=>[{"name"=>"123"}]}, {"name"=>"cde", "children"=>[{"name"=>"456"}, {"name"=>"674"}]}]}

puts JSON.generate(tree)

#=> {"name":"test","children":[{"name":"abc","children":[{"name":"123"}]},{"name":"cde","children":[{"name":"456"},{"name":"674"}]}]}
```